# Flutter Firebase push notification open Specific page

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a simple flutter project and tried to open a specific page each time the user tapped on the notification.  It works great when the app is in the Background state, but when the app is in the terminated state, it redirects to the Home page only, Instead of redirecting to the FunActivity page.

Here is my main.dart

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print('Handling a background message ${message.notification!.title!}');
  }
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}

const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'high_importance_channel',
  'High Importance Notifications',
  importance: Importance.high,
);

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  // Initialize Firebase Messaging for background handling
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  // Initialize Flutter Local Notifications
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  // Set foreground notification presentation options
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  // Retrieve Firebase Cloud Messaging token
  FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("token is $token");
    }
  });

  // Initialize GetStorage for local storage
  await GetStorage.init();

  // Apply custom HTTP overrides if needed
  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();

  // Start the app
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureFirebaseMessagingAndLocalNotifications();

    // Subscribe to the 'all' topic for Firebase Cloud Messaging
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('all');
  }

  void _configureFirebaseMessagingAndLocalNotifications() async {
    // Request permission to receive notifications
    NotificationSettings settings =
    await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print('User granted permission: ${settings.authorizationStatus}');
    }

    // Configure Firebase messaging background handler
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

    // Configure Firebase messaging handler when the app is in the foreground
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      final pageIndex = int.tryParse(message.data['news_id'] ?? '');
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Received message: ${message.notification!.title!}');
        print('Received pageIndex: ${pageIndex.toString()}');
      }
      _displayNotification(message.notification!);
    });

    // Configure Firebase messaging handler when the app is terminated
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print('Message opened from the terminated state: ${message.notification!.title}');
      }
      _openFunActivityWithIndex(message);
    });

    // Initialize the FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
    var initializationSettingsAndroid = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_stat_nu');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }

  Future<void> _displayNotification(RemoteNotification notification) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id,
      channel.name,
      importance: Importance.high,
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      icon: '@drawable/ic_stat_nu',
      onlyAlertOnce: true,
      color: Colors.deepOrange,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, // Notification ID
      channel.name, // Notification title - This is now included in the styleInformation
      null, // Notification message
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'Default_Sound',
    );
    _showNotification(notification.title!);
  }

  void _showNotification(String title,) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      channel.id,
      channel.name,
      importance: Importance.high,
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      icon: '@drawable/ic_stat_nu',
      onlyAlertOnce: true,
      color: Colors.deepOrange,
      fullScreenIntent: true,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      0, // Notification ID
      title, // Notification title
      null, // Notification message
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'Default_Sound',
    );
  }

  void _openFunActivityWithIndex(RemoteMessage message) {
    final pageIndex = int.tryParse(message.data['news_id'] ?? '');
    if (pageIndex != null) {
      Get.to(() => FunActivity(index: pageIndex));
    } else {
      // Handle the case where the index is null or not provided in the notification
      Get.to(() => FunActivity(index: 0)); // Default to the first index or adjust as needed
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OverlaySupport(
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'PK Quiz',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please suggest to me why the app is working for the background state and not in the terminated state.
I am getting all the data from Firebase notification.